# Android App Crash NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, crash

I've done the searching and it seems to be a case by case basis as to what's causing this.  Though, someone who truly understands it will quite possibly disagree.

My buttons going from my main screen into other activities work just fine, the only difference with the one that doesn't work is that it's actually pulling a class/variable from another .java file and so I'm sure I haven't implemented it correctly.

It's a Singleton class:

GLOBAL.JAVA

```
//Constructor 
//
protected Global() {
    getInstance();
}


//Singleton Method
//
public static Global getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        initialize();
        instance = new Global();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I have a few (static)class structures(I use the term structures because I program primarily in C++, and to me, that's what they are) that are placed inside the Global file/class, along with this array that holds all the data for the program `static questionStruct[] questions = new questionStruct[TOTAL_QUESTIONS];`

The `initialize();` function called from the `getInstance()`(Singleton Method) simply fills in the data into the `questionStruct[]` array.

I have a method to return a string

```
public static String getQ(int q){

    return questions[q].q;
}
```

In the .java file that gets called from the button pressed, I have `placeData();` just to test things out, and in that function:

```
public void placeData() {

    String testString = ("Testing Text: " + Global.getQ(3));

    TextView Q = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testingText);
    Q.setText(testString);


}
```

and lastly... hopefully... the TextView where it's supposed to show up in the XML file:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testingText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And here's my official error I believe is the indicator to the crash, that only occurs when I press the button to initialize this activity.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{godwin.com.study/godwin.com.study.practice}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String godwin.com.study.Global$questionStruct.q' on a null object reference
```

Thoughts???

EDIT:

Classes (like a structure in C++) inside of Global.Java

```
class answerStruct
{
    String a;
    boolean status;
}


//Structure for Questions
//
class questionStruct
{
    String q;

    answerStruct[] answer = new answerStruct[TOTAL_ANSWERS];

}
```

The "initialize()" function:

```
public static void initialize() {

    questions[0].q = "Question # 1";
    questions[0].answer[0].a = "Q1A1";
    questions[0].answer[0].status = true;
    questions[0].answer[1].a = "Q1A2";
    questions[0].answer[1].status = false;

    ...And so on...Forever
}
```

Comment: Where is `questionStruct` declared?

Comment: What is `questions[q].q;`? I don't think you need that last .q, just `questions[q]`? Full trace and line numbers might help too.

Comment: It's clear that the problem is that when you call `getQ` for some value of `q`, `questions[q]` is `null`. This points to a problem in the `initialize()` method but it's impossible to tell you how to fix it unless you post the code for that method.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the replies.  Hopefully I can clear some things up.  `quesitonStruct` is a class declared inside of Global.java.  the `.q` in the variable `quesitons[q].q` is actually a String inside of the "questions[]" class array.  And the initialize method fills in the array with information.  I suppose I left a few things out, but I didn't think I needed to post everything.  Tried to find a happy medium between posting nothing and everything, haha.  I'll edit the code to hopefully supply what you need to help me out.  Thanks again.

Comment: If need be, I can remove the current code segments from the original question and just copy/past the entire files... I'm thinking the ones involved are 2x .java files and 1x XML.

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate an array of objects in Java like this:

```
static questionStruct[] questions = new questionStruct[TOTAL_QUESTIONS];
```

You are only allocating an array of object references, you aren't actually allocating the objects themselves. It's kind of like you allocated an array of pointers in C++, but they don't point to anything yet.

At the top of your initialize() function, you can allocate all the questionStruct objects, and also the answers for each in a nested for loop, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL_QUESTIONS; i++)
{
    questions[i] = new questionStruct();
    for(int j = 0; j < TOTAL_QUESTIONS; j++)
        questions[i].answer[j] = new answerStruct();
}
```

Then you can go through and initialize all the fields in the structs as you are doing.

Comment: Getting on the right track, I'm following, but the way I see it, the setup would be repetitive.  Granted, I'm tired as heck and this issue is making me cross-eyed all on its own, haha.  But, wouldn't the declaration of  `static questionStruct[] questions = new questionStruct[TOTAL_QUESTIONS];` and the 'for loops' you provided be repetitive?  I understand your reasoning for suggesting the for loops.  It makes sense, even in my current state of mind.  But shouldn't I get rid of the first declaration?  Honestly, I'm sure if I worked on this tomorrow it'd make sense, but right now... not so much.

Comment: No, you need both declarations. The first to allocate the array itself, and the allocations in the loop to allocate each object that is stored in the array.

Comment: I can't quite mark your answer as THE answer, but it definitely helped.  I actually had an issue elsewhere that was causing the crash, but I also know that I didn't implement the singleton class right AND obviously I was mistaken in declaring the array.  So, thank you for your input, it really did help.